# Multiple repo permissions within project

Tags: azure-devops

I have a project on Azure Devops that contains numerous repo's. I need a way to create groups for certain repo's and only allow members of those group to be able to see a certain repo associated with the groups they are a member of.

What I have done in the past is have one group that I explicitly allow a repo access to the group and deny access to all other repo's. This however becomes a problem if a user is a member of more than one of these groups as the DENY seems to take precedence and the user is denied from all repo's.

Has anyone set up anything similar successfully?

Answer (score 1):

Don't use an explicit Deny permission. There are three levels:

- Explicit Deny ("Deny")
- Implicit Deny ("Not set")
- Explicit Allow ("Allow")

An explicit deny has the highest precedence; if you explicitly deny someone access, they will *never* have access, regardless of whether an "allow" is set elsewhere.

Meanwhile, "not set" simply means "unless explicitly allowed, deny access".